# About generating responsive image gallery from any folder on Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, responsive-images

I created collection for portfolio contents in my Jekyll and I am currently able to list all images from any folder [with this guide](https://jekyllcodex.org/without-plugin/image-gallery/). But there are image files named with @2x for displaying sharp images on high density displays like `image1.png`, `image1@2x.png` etc.

So how do I exclude @2x image files in gallery and put in `srcset=""` property in `<img>` tag for generating responsive image gallery.

---

This is my sample `.md` file:

```
---
layout: work-detail
---
{% include screenshot.html folder="/images-folder/" %}
```

This is include file for generating gallery:

```
<div class="screenshot screenshot--grid">
{% for file in site.static_files %}
  {% if file.path contains include.folder %}
    {% if file.extname == '.jpg' or 
      file.extname == '.jpeg' or 
      file.extname == '.JPG' or 
      file.extname == '.png' or 
      file.extname == '.PNG' or 
      file.extname == '.JPEG' %}

      {% assign filenameparts = file.path | split: "/" %}
      {% assign filename = filenameparts | last | replace: file.extname,"" %}
            <img src="{{ file.path }}" alt="">
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are all named properly/consistently you could do:

```
{% unless file.path contains "@2x" %}
  {% assign filepath2x = file.path | replace: file.extname,"@2x" | append: file.extname %}
  <img src="{{ file.path }}" srcset="{{ filepath2x }} 1000w" />
{% endunless %}
```

Note that this code should replace (just) the output of the image tag, so this part:

```
<img src="{{ file.path }}" alt="">
```

What this code does is:

- It prevents outputting images with "@2x" in the filename (it skips them).
- It creates a new variable called 'filepath2x'. This variable is a copy of the file.path, but with ".extension" (.jpg) replaced by "@2x.extension" (@2x.jpg)
- It outputs the image tag with an extra srcset attribute and fills this attribute with this new variable.

I have used a random srcset setting (1000w). Please adjust this to fit your project.